# a macro on templates

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Not sure if what am trying to do is bad but here's my question:
I have a some template functions like

```
std::vector<T> operator - (const std::vector<T>& data1, const std::vector<T>& data2);
std::vector<T> operator * (const std::vector<T>& data1, const std::vector<T>& data2);
std::vector<T> operator & (const std::vector<T>& data1, const std::vector<T>& data2);
```

....and so on.  All of these functions have exactly the same definition except for the operator, so I was trying to write a macro like this

```
#define _BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET (OP_TYPE)
  template <typename T> \
  std::vector<T> operator OP_TYPE (const std::vector<T>& data1, const std::vector<T>& data2)\
  {\
    std::vector<T> result;\
    result.push_back(data1.begin().val OP_TYPE data1.begin().val)/*sample implementation*/\
    return result;\
  }

_BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET (&)
_BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET (+)
```

And I get a bunch of errors

```
Error   1   error C2833: 'operator OP_TYPE' is not a recognized operator or type
Error   2   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : 'newline'
Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

...and more
Can anyone see whats the problem with this?

Thanks for any help.

CV

Comment: How are you going to `+` two vector that contains `T`? And how are you going to `&` and `-` two vectors?

Comment: my bad.. that was a typo , edited code

Comment: ok.. as Kerrek SB and ildjarn pointed out, they are silly syntax mistakes.

Comment: Nice question, I didn't know you could send non-variable-like stuff (like operators) to macros. It's beautiful, I love macros ...*tears*

Comment: Every time someone uses a macro, God kills a kitten. Every time someone abuses operator overloading, God kills a kitten. Every time someone abuses operator overloading with macros, kittens look straight at the eyes of Death and face extinction. (BTW: Have you considered using `valarray<T>` instead of `vector<T>`?)

Comment: @ David Rodríguez: lol. well, the scope of the macro is within a cpp file. And am using the operators to write mathematical equations on objects of my class. the basic element is a 3D point and I have matrices and vectors of 3D points. So to perform addition on two matrices or vectors directly am doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No space before the macro argument list!

```
#define _BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET(OP_TYPE) ...
                            ^^^
```

Comment: ahhh , damn it.. such silly mistakes.. I hate myself for that

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah, yes, the first newline went unescaped. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid space before the macro argument list and missed escaping the newline after it:

```
#define _BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET(OP_TYPE) \
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between the macro name and it's arguments.

```
#define _BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET(OP_TYPE)
```

Add `\` to the first line of your template

```
#define _BINARY_OP_ON_DATASET(OP_TYPE)\
```

Remove the minor errors, such as the `;` you forgot in the second line of your function body

```
result.push_back(data1.begin().val+data1.begin().val);
```

And it compiles well!

Answer (score 0):

I think repeating the definition will be simpler than macro-fying them :)  Sometimes it's just better to repeat yourself than to eek out more typing efficiency.

Comment: In some very simple cases maybe, but you may have code that is large and needs to be repeated. Repeating the definition means that if you change something in one, you have to go change it in all of them which introduces possible inconsistency.

Comment: Ah well, I tried lol.  Wish we could have done without the downvotes though :\

Comment: alrite I'll give u one up to remove the -1

Comment: @blueskin Much appreciated... In hindsight, I didn't really provide an answer to your question, but was rather thinking in terms of what I'd (not) want to see in my own code :\  I can see how this would be useful on a large codebase though, as Shahbaz stated.

Comment: I was basically using for the same purpose, I started writing templates for my functions and after sometime I realized that I would probably end up writing about 30-40 functions. So thought of creating macros, I always want to write lesser code because its more maintainable and lesser bugs. (of course harder to debug in this case)